# Finding intersection points of the Line command

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions

Suppose I have two lists to which I apply the `Line` command for example

```
A = {{-4,0},{4,0}}
B = {{0,4},{0,-4}}
```

and I take `Line[A]` and `Line[B]`. Is there a way to get Mathematica to tell me the intersection points of the line? Of course this is a very simple example, in practice the lines would have many defining points to approximate a curve.

further questions: How about if I had $n$ lists? Could I ask to find the intersection points in some bounded region only?

Answer (score 6):

Join each of your collections of lines using a `RegionUnion` into a single region, then intersect both regions with `RegionIntersection` like so:

```
redLines = {
  Line[{{-2.`, 4.`}, {-1.5`, 2.25`}, {-1.`, 1.`}, {-0.5`, 0.25`}, {0.`, 0.`}, {0.5`, 0.25`}, {1.`, 1.`}, {1.5`, 2.25`}, {2.`, 4.`}}]
, Line[{{2, -1}, {2.5, 2}}]
};
blueLines = {
  Line[{{22.`, -3.`}, {15.49`, -2.3`}, {9.96`, -1.6`}, {5.41`, -0.9`}, {1.84`, -0.2`}, {-0.75`, 0.5`}, {-2.36`, 1.2`}, {-2.99`, 1.9`}, {-2.64`, 2.6`}, {-1.31`, 3.3`}, {1.`, 4.`}, {4.29`, 4.7`}, {8.56`, 5.4`}, {13.81`, 6.1`}, {20.04`, 6.8`}}]
, Line[{{-3, 1}, {2, 2}}]
};

intersections = RegionIntersection[RegionUnion@redLines, RegionUnion@blueLines];
isectCoordinates = Flatten[MeshPrimitives[intersections, 0] /. Point -> List, 1];
Graphics[{Red, redLines, Blue, blueLines, Black, PointSize[Large],intersections}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-5, 5}}]
```

[image: line intersections]

And if you want to extract the lines from a shape *(e.g square, triangle etc.)* then use `MeshPrimitives[shape, 1]`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll give it a go. Is there a way to extract the coordinates of the intersection using this method?

Comment: You don't need to extract them - I've already calculated them and that's what this line does `intersections = RegionIntersection[RegionUnion@redLines, RegionUnion@blueLines];` On the result, replace the `Point` heads with `List` if you want them in that form.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean about replacing the `Point` heads with `List`. The output is a mesh and I have no experience with these in Mathematica.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake - this will get you the points `MeshPrimitives[intersections, 0]` - I've added `isectCoordinates` in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

#### `` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections ``

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];

findIntersections = Complement[Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[Join[##]], 
  Join @@ Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections /@ {##}] &;
```

Using `redLines` and `blueLines` from flinty's answer:

```
intersections = findIntersections[redLines, blueLines]
```

> ```
> {{-1.73595,3.07582}, {-0.648352,0.472527}, {0.385965,0.192982}, {-1.14815,1.37037}, 
>  {1.34783,1.86957}, {2.12405,-0.255696}}
> ```

```
Graphics[{Red, redLines, Blue, blueLines, Black, PointSize[Large], Point@intersections}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2, 5}}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
SeedRandom[1]
greenLines = {Line[RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {8, 2}]], 
   BezierCurve[RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {7, 2}]]};

intersections = findIntersections[redLines, blueLines, greenLines]
```

> ```
>  {{-1.73595,3.07582}, {-1.63671,1.27266}, {-1.43717,0.798769}, 
>   {-1.214,1.3572}, {-1.14815,1.37037}, {-1.13457,1.33642}, 
>   {-0.648352,0.472527},{-0.601914,0.459977}, {-0.541359,0.312038}, 
>   {-0.487964,0.42918},{-0.444653,0.222327}, {-0.373226,0.398169}, 
>   {-0.295139,0.147569},{0.385965,0.192982}, {1.01337,0.0234133}, 
>   {1.16581,-0.0177874}, {1.34783,1.86957}, {2.12405,-0.255696}, 
>   {2.41381,1.48283}}
> ```

```
Graphics[{Red, redLines, Blue, blueLines, Green, greenLines, 
  Black, PointSize[Medium], Point@intersections}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 5}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not well acquainted with using these types of Graphics commands, is there some advantage this code has over flinty's?

Comment: @math, one advantage I am aware of is that it can handle `BezierCurve`, `BSplineCurve` as well as `Line` primitives  in the input lists without additional processing. Region/Mesh functionality do not work with  bezier and b-spline curves yet.

Comment: Thank you for this!